# Problem with laravel eloquent relationship - can't access relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am facing a problem with an Eloquent relationship. I am new and trying to learn.

I have 3 models:

1. `village` model - contain village names
2. `Patient` model - containing patient info
3. `Serial` model - containing patient serials

#### Relationships

- `village` model has many `patients` and `patient` belongs to the `village` model
- `Patient` model has many `Serial` models and the `serial` model belongs to the `patient` model

The `serial` model has date fields. I am making queries to get `Serials` whose dates match `today` and try to get the related model data.

#### Model codes

##### `village` has many `Patient`

```
public function patient()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Patient::class);
}
```

##### `Patient` model belongs to `village`

```
public function village()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Village::class);
}
```

##### `Patient` has many `serials`

```
public function serials()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Serial::class);
}
```

##### `Serial` belongs to `patient`

```
public function patient()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Patient::class);
}
```

---

I am getting `Patient` using `Serial::where('date', '2022-05-11')->with(['patient'])->get();`.

But I want to get the nested model like `Serial::where('date', '2022-05-11')->with(['patient.village'])->get();`

I am getting `village` undefined! How can I get the `village` through `Serial`, please?

Comment: you are calling mutiple relation with wrong syntax, use comma instead of dot `with(['patient' , 'village'])`

Comment: Thanks for your replay. But the Serial model has no direct relationship with village. But let me try!

Comment: By this way, it is making error -  "Call to undefined relationship [village] on model [App\Models\Serial]."

Comment: Actually The Patient model belongs to Village model and Patient model has many Serial Model. Need to Get Village from Patient model

Answer (score 0):

I find the error.
I have problem with foreignId constrained
I wrote relationship for patient like -

```
$table->integer('village')->nullable()
```

But it should be -

```
$table->foreignId('village_id')->constrained()->nullable()
```